# Illustrator CS6 align objects keyboard shortcut

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, alignment, shortcuts

Is it possible to create a custom keyboard shortcut in Adobe Illustrator CS6 on OS X 10.8.5 to align and/or distribute objects (center/left/right/etc)? I know I can open the Align window, but I would like to apply the alignment with a shortcut.

`Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts` doesn't provide an option and it isn't clear to me how, if possible, to write my own in a keyboard shortcut file (e.g. `/Users/user/Library/Preferences/Adobe Illustrator CS6 Settings/en_US/custom.kys`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can. There's no way to "write your own shortcut file". If the shortcut is not available in `Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts...` then that command/element is not available.

You could use scripting but an easier route would be to create an **action** (or collection of actions) and **assign an F-key shortcut** to the action(s).

Answer (score 0):

if you go to System Preferences >> Keyboard and activate "Use all F1,F2 etc keys..." you will only have to use F2 after teh action is set. No Fn Key needed.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Chipatu Mwasinga, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. Could you explain how your answer helps OP set a shortcut to align/distribute objects? If you have any questions, please see the help center or ping one of us in the Graphic Design Chat once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

Autohotkey ...plus Pulover . Create your own script. I had bought an external numpad for those specific actions that should save tons of time .